Geometry Nodes: Separate each instance on a curve as individual object keeping each instance's original pivot position
I’m new to Blender. I want to export each instance on a geometry node curve as its own object (for a unity game) but keep the original pivot for each one. When I make instances real they all merge into one mesh and after separating by loose parts all the objects have 0,0,0 for their rotation. Any tips?

Make instances real is a correct option, but make sure, that As Instance is checked:

Then in object mode, press Ctrl + A → Make instances real.
As you see, rotation is preserved:


blinks stupidly well my answer was a waste of time. lollllllllll. I only use the Convert to Mesh to apply  the GN mods, so I never even knew that this function did this. Lmao. Ya learn something new every day. ¯_(ツ)_/¯
